# Use one power source for two atmega chips

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, atmega, atmega328p

I'm working on a big project recently that requires 2 atmega chips one to handle input midi signals and one to transmit output midi signals. Because of the complexity of the project I cannot use one chip to receive and transmit midi and simultaneously control everything fast enough. Is there a way to use a common power input for both chips? I'm thinking one Voltage Regulator sending 12V parallel to two 5V Voltage Regulators powering each atmega chip. Is this going to work or is there any other way to do it like directly connect 12V DC input from external power supply to the 2 regulators?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm going to use one atmega2560 for lots of output and an atmega328 for input if this in any way helpful.

Comment: Arduinos already have 2 Atmegas in them (the main MCU and the one that handles USB communication), so clearly its viable.

Comment: Its good to draw a circuit diagram with the tool so we know exactly what you are indicating.

Comment: The arduino does use 2 atmegas but the programmer one is powered by the USB cable. I can post the circuit but i dont know if it would be any help

Comment: @FrankF. How about when you power the board with the USB? What powers the main MCU then? The **same 5V that powers the USB chip.**

Comment: Well i guess you are right... Will one regulator be suficient for more than just programming like blinking LEDs?

Comment: The "programmer" Atmega already "blinks LEDs", so.. clearly its viable... You really need to get into specifics, otherwise all we can give is generic answers..

Answer (score 4):

If the 5V regulator can source enough current then you can just use it for both chips directly.

Comment: Using an lm1117 5V version with a 9V power source for house appliences can it give enough current for both of them? If I'm not misstaken he lm1117 datasheet says it can provide up to 1200mA typical current.

Comment: The current the power supply needs to provide will depend on the activty of the ATMegas, and on the requirements of other parts of your circuit.  You may be able to estimate the total current requirement from the datasheets, or measure the current once you have built the unit.